# rpart.plot Error: box.palette is neither a color or a palette

Tags: r, rpart

I used the following code below and I got an error. All variables are numeric and b variables have 4 different conditions (0,3,4,5).

```
tree=rpart(a~b,data,method='class', cp=0.05)
rpart.plot(tree)
```

The Error I got:

> Error: box.palette: c("#F7FCF5", "#EEF8EA", "#E5F5E0", "#D6EFD0",
>   "#C7E9C0", "#B4E1AD", "#A1D99B", "#8ACE88", "#74C476") is neither a
>   color nor a palette. Try something like box.palette="blue" or
>   box.palette="Blues". The predefined palettes are (with an optional "-"
>   prefix):   Grays Greys Greens Blues Browns Oranges Reds Purples   Gy
>   Gn Bu Bn Or Rd Pu (alternative names for the above palettes)   BuGn
>   BuBn GnRd etc.  (two-color diverging palettes: any combination of two
>   palettes)   RdYlGn GnYlRd BlGnYl YlGnBl (three color palettes)

So I tried the following code but still the same error:
rpart.plot(tree, box.palette="auto")

If I eliminate cp=0.05 on my first line (tree=rpart(a~b,data,method='class'), the tree comes out but condition 3 is stated as 'Unused' and only 0,4,5 are used in the tree so I can't have a full decision tree.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `rpart.plot(tree,box.palette = "blue")` or `rpart.plot(tree,box.palette = "green")`, for example.

Or if you want to define a color yourself you could use `box.palette = rgb(.5,.5,.5,.5)` (the numbers represent percentages of red, green, blue, transparency, all values between 0 and 1)

Comment: Thanks but what happens is the tree doesn't come out but only just one box showing as if it was an anova method. I wanted to use class method, and ultimately I want the class 3 to be showing in the tree also just like 0,4 and 5.